# How to hold together large packet of paper

Tags: office-supplies, paper

Large packets of paper are often used for play scripts and large internet printouts. Stapling them would not work; the stapler is not that powerful. What can I do to put together this large packet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use binder clips:
[image]
They hold tightly, are relatively inexpensive, are available in large sizes and cause minimal damage to the paper (they do not puncture it as staples do).

Comment: All answers are good, but this is probably the only one that can be considered a lifehack

Comment: Actually binder clips are made for that kind of task, therefore this is technically not a lifehack since it uses something for its intended purpose.

Comment: that awkward moment when i finally learn what binder clips are actually for

Answer (score 1):

Drill a series of holes down one side and "sew"it all together by threading string through the holes. On the last hole, loop back through threading the opposite way until you get to the start and tie the string off.

Answer (score 1):

1. Treasury tags or India tags: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treasury_tag

[image]

2. Paper fasteners with washers, sometime sold with hole punch:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used edge binders for printouts and documents (this link shows [one intended for 60 sheets of A4](http://www.officevalue.ie/office-supplies/files/slide-binders/durable-spinebar-6mm-a4-transparent-pk-50-293119.html) ).  They come in different sizes but I've never seen them thicker than about 10mm so it depends on whether you're talking about hundreds of pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Spiral or coil bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coil_binding) come in many different sizes:

[image: spiral bindings]

The colors can be used to distinguish, say different roles for play scripts. Spiral-bound books lie flat easily, but multiple ones don't fit well in a bookcase, since the binding is thicker than the paper. If this is a problem, think about other ways of binding.

The necessary machines to actually punch the holes into the paper and insert it in the binding are available in your friendly office supplies shop:

[image: spiral binding machine]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a cost effective way to do this rather than rummaging through products online. I would suggest hole punching through the sheets of paper and get yourself some binding rings, they're super cheap and easy to store!

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

You can get them in various sizes to suit your needs and use the tab sticky notes or dividers to separate plays, these also are very cheap to buy. 
 
Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

 Figure 3 
[image: Figure 3]

Answer (score 0):

Get some rare earth magnets. Depending on the magnet field strength, you can bind large amounts of paper together. I have used them multiple times to keep things together that I didn't want punctured.

Some downsides to using this method: the magnets want to stick to each other more than through the paper, so stacking bound documents would be almost impossible; they are expensive; magnets that are strong enough can cause damage to magnetic media (think computer hard drive); magnets can snap together when close, possibly causing injury in the process; extremely strong magnets are difficult to separate.

Answer (score 0):

use linen binding tape, it's cheap and easy.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One old-fashioned method is to wrap the stack of paper in a sheet of (larger) paper, like the wrapper a ream comes in, held in place with tape or elastic bands.